# Functional derivative of line integral

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, line-integrals

If we can interpret the line integral of a function over a path as a functional. What would be its functional derivative?

For instance, in this example, let $\gamma$ be a path in $\mathbb{R}^3$. And consider $\boldsymbol{A}(\boldsymbol{r})$ a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then we can interpret the line integral over path $\gamma$ as a functional, since, for a fixed path, the integral sends functions to real numbers.
$$
F[\boldsymbol{A}(\boldsymbol{r})] = \int_\gamma \boldsymbol{A}(\boldsymbol{r}) \cdot d\boldsymbol{r}.
$$

Using the definition of Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative), the variation is given by
$$
\delta F[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{\phi}] = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{F[\boldsymbol{A}+\epsilon \boldsymbol{\phi}]-F[\boldsymbol{A}]}{\epsilon},
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ is the test function.

After substitution, I get
$$
\delta F[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{\phi}] = \int_\gamma \boldsymbol{\phi}(\boldsymbol{r})\cdot d\boldsymbol{r}.
$$
To obtain the functional derivative we need an expression of the form
$$
\delta F[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{\phi}] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \sum_j \frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi_j}(\boldsymbol{r}) \phi_j(\boldsymbol{r}') dV',
$$
where $\phi_j$ is the j-component of $\boldsymbol{\phi}$. However, I fail to identify
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \sum_j \frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi_j}(\boldsymbol{r}') \phi_j(\boldsymbol{r}') dV' \stackrel{?}{=} \int_\gamma \phi(\boldsymbol{r})\cdot d\boldsymbol{r}.
$$
I would guess that the functional derivative will be some kind of delta distribution in the directions perpendicular to the curve $\gamma$ but I am not sure how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: $F$ is linear in $A$ so wouldn't the derivative just be the map $\phi\to\int\phi\cdot\mathrm{d}r$?

Comment: @whpowell96 The functional differential is indeed the map you mention, but is there a way of expressing it as a functional derivative? In other words, to express the line integral as a volume integral (perhaps using some distributions)?

Comment: I don't see why the functional derivative would involve values outside the domain of integration.

Comment: I removed the functional calculus tag as that refers moreso to maps of the form $f \mapsto f(A)$ giving to meaning to applying a function of the real variable to a linear operator $A$. It's just a heads up, mis-tagging is not at all the end of the world.